# Accessing data in a Filemaker 18 file via ODBC in Python

Tags: python, odbc, filemaker

[image]
When trying to access data stored in a Filemaker 18 file via ODBC for analysis in Python following error occurs:

> *Traceback (most recent call last): pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('28000', '[28000] [FileMaker][FileMaker]  (802): Unable to open file')*

ODBC has been installed in Filemaker and the test via the 'ODBC Manager' tool is successful.

Python 3.8 code used:

```
import pypyodbc

con_str = 'DSN=Test_db;Database=Test_db;UID=User;PWD=password;'

db = pypyodbc.connect(con_str)
```

Many thanks for ANY ideas on how to read/write data from/to a Filemaker DB from Python.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need to specify a driver in the connection string.  ex:

```
 connection_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=..."
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment Mark. 

Unfortunately, the result remains unchanged (pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('28000', '[28000] [FileMaker][FileMaker]  (802): Unable to open file')). 

I looked up the Driver Name in the ODBC Manager app (=FileMaker ODBC, stored at /Library/ODBC/FileMaker ODBC.bundle/Contents/MacOS/fmodbc.so).) and changed the con_str to con_str = 'Driver={FileMaker ODBC};DSN=Test_db;Database=Test_db;UID=User;PWD=password;' 

I also tried a few variations - all with the same result. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

In 'OBDC Manager' a User DSN or a System DSN can be set up. Despite working on the same system and under the same user login, it only works with a System DSN.

Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the "ANY ideas" part, as an alternative to ODBC you can also use the FileMaker DATA API to connect to your FileMaker DB.

Comment: Note: you need 'FileMaker server' (at additional monthly cost) in order to use the data API, the question doesn't mention using FM server